# crop section from resizeable UIImageView's image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview, crop

I have a UIImageView that gets its image from UIImagePickerController
The UIImageView is set to Aspect Fit
Im using gesture recognizers to move, scale, and rotate this UIImageView

I have a second, much smaller UIImageView
The second UIImageView is in front of and centered with the first

What I would like to do is be able to move, scale, and rotate the first UIImageView into position, then press a button to create a new image containing only the section of the original image that can be seen within the bounds of the second UIImageView

I have tried quite a few ways of cropping the image without success. Everything I tried will crop the image but the returned image is not what I expect. What I get back appears to be a rotated portion of the top, right hand, section of the FULL SIZE image.

I am using the UIImage Categories from [Trevor’s Bike Shed](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)

My code:

**.h**

```
@interface BubbleBossViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *smallCropperWindow;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewForChosenImage;
    IBOutlet UIView *canvas;
    CGFloat _lastScale;
    CGFloat _lastRotation;
    CGFloat _firstX;
    CGFloat _firstY;
    CAShapeLayer *_marque;

}
@property BOOL newMedia;
- (IBAction)useCamera:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)useCameraRoll:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)crop:(id)sender;

@end
```

**relevant .m**
-(void)crop:(id)sender{

```
smallCropperWindow.image=[imageViewForChosenImage.image croppedImage: (CGRect)smallCropperWindow.frame];
```

}

**in UIImage+Resize.h**

```
- (UIImage *)croppedImage:(CGRect)bounds;
```

**in UIImage+Resize.m**

```
- (UIImage *)croppedImage:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGFloat scale = MAX(self.scale, 1.0f);
    CGRect scaledBounds = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x * scale, bounds.origin.y * scale, bounds.size.width * scale, bounds.size.height * scale);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], scaledBounds);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:self.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return croppedImage;
}
```

Screenshot showing issue:
[image]

The small square in the middle should be filled with the babbie's face not a section of the floor from the full size image.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you get the mistake you are making?

Comment: I do now thank you. Working on it now please see below

Comment: Can you please post your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculations you are doing seem incorrect. Try this,

1. First you have to make image aspect fit.
2. Then find the ratio `heightRatio=image.size.height/imageView.frame.height;`
3. Then find the ratio `weidthRatio=image.size.width/imageView.frame.width;`

Now instead of passing your `smallCropperWindow.frame` you have to do three things,

1. Translate center of small croppedWindow.Lots of calculation will go because aspect fit image will not start from origin of imageview.
2. Scale the width and height of your croppedWindow and pass this frame for cropping.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, im working on that now. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "Translate center of small croppedWindow.Lots of calculation will go because aspect fit image will not start from origin of imageview."?

Comment: you place your croppview with respect to what you see which can be smaller then actual image so if real image is bigger or has diffrent dimention you have to change the center of croppview i.e 2,2 center on screen might actually be 8,8 on real image.Since rotation is involved so calculation will be tough

Comment: And when you say "First you have to make image aspect fit." do you mean the original image or the new imagae I am creating

Comment: you have to make original image to be cropped aspect fit so that you crop what you see.If you distort the image then crop view will sho diffrent image and cropp diffrent image

Comment: drop rotation if its not absolutely necessary

Comment: Thanks amar. I have implemented as you described and dropped the rotation. Working great now.